# Как в Selenium на Python в форму или в textarea поместить текст с переходами на новую строку

Tags: python, selenium, строковый-литерал

Мне нужно отправлять сообщения в WhatsApp с помощью Selenium. Для этого я использую такой код:

```
    text =   
 """\u0427\u0430:\n\u0418\u0441\u043f\u043e\u043b\u044c\u0437\u0442\u04 
    35 \u043e\u0434\u0438\u043d\u043e\u0447\u043d\u044b\u0435 
    \u043a\u0430\u0432\u044b\u0447\u043a \u0430):\n"""
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@dir='ltr']").send_keys(text)
```

По идеи \n служит для перехода на новую строку. Как я понял \n равносильно нажатию Enter, при котором вместо перехода на новую строку, он отправляет сообщение. Мне напротив нужно, чтобы весь текст был в одном сообщении, даже с использованием абзацев.

Пробовал делать так, но у меня нет возможности проверять текст и каждый раз при переходе на новую строку выполнять. Enter+Shift как раз переходит на новую строку.

```
ActionChains(driver) \
    .key_down(Keys.SHIFT) \
    .key_down(Keys.ENTER) \
    .key_up(Keys.ENTER)\
    .key_up(Keys.SHIFT)\
    .perform()
```

Comment: если Enter посылает форму, то замените \n на Shift + Enter. "у меня нет возможности проверять текст" -- это не правда: `for line in text.splitlines(): .send_keys(line) perform_shift_newline_action_chain`

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Python and Selenium - Avoid submit form when send_keys() with newline](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45236253/4279)